# poly2nb {spdep} how identify if two cities are neighbours

Tags: r, spdep, neighbour

I'm trying to identify if two cites are neighbours using spdep::poly2nb function, but it returns a list with numbers that i can't understand.
For example,

```
shp_ce <- rgdal::readOGR(dsn = "folder", layer = "23MUE250GC_SIR")

neighborhood <- poly2nb(pl = shp)

city_1 <- c('City A', 'City B', 'City C')
city_2 <- c('City D', 'City E', 'City F')
cities <- data.frame(city_1, city_2)
```

I need to identify if each pair of cities in dataframe are neigbours, but poly2nb return vectors of vectors only with numbers.

```
neighborhood [[1]]
> 12 33 152
```

How could I get it?

Comment: `neighbourhood` is the adjacency list for **polygons** in `shp_ce` which you've read from a file. How does "City A" and "City B" etc relate to that? Are they named columns in `shp_ce`? Is it one polygon per city? Here we see that the first polygon in `shp_ce` is next to polygons 12, 33 and 152. These are row numbers in `shp_ce`.

Comment: Yes, they are named columns in `shp_ce`. The shape has 184 polygons one per city. Oh thanks, the numbers are sequentially set.

Comment: You should probably look at the `sf` package for spatial data now, instead of `rgdal` and the `sp` data classes - these are going away soon and are replaced by `sf` packages and data types. The `spdep` functions like `poly2nb` do work with `sf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out if City B and City E are neighbours:

First find out which row in the data matches the city (I'm using `city` as the city name column here):

```
> which(shp_ce$city=="City B")
[1] 2
> which(shp_ce$city=="City E")
[1] 5
```

So City B is row 2, City E is row 5 in the data.

Then see if "5" appears in the neighbours for row 2:

```
> neighborhood[[2]]
[1]  1  3 18
```

Nope. You can do this as a logical test with `%in%`. "Is 5 in the list of neighbours for row 2?" becomes:

```
> 5 %in% neighborhood[[2]]
[1] FALSE
```

The neighbourhood list tells is that City B (row 2) is a neighbour of:

```
> shp_ce$city[neighborhood[[2]]]
[1] "City A" "City C" "City R"
```

That's the principle - you'll need to loop over your dataframe rows to test each of those city pairs.

As a one-liner you might want to use:

```
> which(shp_ce$city=="City B") %in% neighborhood[[ which(shp_ce$city=="City A") ]]
[1] TRUE
> which(shp_ce$city=="City B") %in% neighborhood[[ which(shp_ce$city=="City E") ]]
[1] FALSE
```

which says A and B are neighbours, but B and E aren't.